# foreach inversly

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

Is there posible way to make foreach iterate through the collection from the end to the begining?

```
int[] fibarray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
    foreach (int i in fibarray)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

How to display inversly with foreach ?

Comment: BTW, the proper Fibonacci seq is 0, 1, 1, 2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (int i in fibArray.Reverse())
```

But a normal for loop will be more efficient:

```
for( int index = fibArray.Length - 1; index >= 0; --index ) {
    int i = fibArray[index];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Reverse()`:

```
int[] fibarray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
foreach (int i in fibarray.Reverse())
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

In general `foreach` must support any `IEnumerable` which only support forward enumeration of items in the collection, as an alternative to `Reverse()` you could write your own optimized implementation that works on an `IList` which provides an indexer.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (int i in fibarray.Reverse<int>())
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Use `for` instead, or modify your collection to be in the desired order before iterating.

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerable.Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)

```
foreach (int i in fibarray.Reverse)
    System.Console.Writeline(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible by default. You would need to create your own class with an iterator with that capability:

[C# .NET Iterator Example : Reverse Iteration](http://shiman.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/c-net-iterator-example-reverse-iteration/)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. You cannot change the behavior of foreach. If you want to do this without returning a new array (like calling Reverse), then use a for loop.

```
int[] fibarray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
for (int i = fibarray.Length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: You changed the meaning of `i` to be an index, not the array content.  And you have an off-by-one error.

Comment: Though I missed the -1 (doh), the function of i-- provides the same result as --i in this case.

Comment: That's was the off-by-one I was referring to.  Now you just need to actually print the contents of `fibarray`, since you changed the meaning of `i` from *element value* to `*index*.

Comment: ITs an example on how to reverse a for loop.. he can do whatever he wants to inside the loop, so I don't really see what you are trying to make a point of.

Comment: BTW `Reverse` doesn't return a new array, it returns an iterator that goes through the array backwards.  Only important for really really big arrays I suspect.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, because the underlying framework creates a buffer, and returns the buffer in reverse order, not the original source.

Comment: I thought you meant it returned an array with the items in reverse order, that doesn't happen.  To be compatible with streaming enumerators, yes it has to grab all the source data into a buffer.